# how to use curl to pass parameters to the form of the https://www.worldtimeserver.com/ website

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to write a bash program that given a country name
displays the time in that country. For that I am using the https://www.worldtimeserver.com/

The idea is the get the country as a parameter to the bash program and pass it
to the web site to search for it. I am using curl and I tried many possible
ways to pass a parameter to the web site, but nothing worked.

The relevant html code of the web site looks as follows:

```
Choose a location to see current local time right now:<br />
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$locationddl" id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_locationddl" onchange="gotocurrenttime(this);" style="max-width:100%">
<option value="">select a location</option>
<option value="UTC">(UTC/GMT)</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">&#197;land Islands</option>
```

So, I tried the following code in bash to try to pass "AF"
which is the code for Afghanistan, to the web site for a search.

I typed the following from the command line:

> curl -X POST -F 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$locationddl=AF'
>   https://www.worldtimeserver.com/ >| tmp

Then I looked at the tmp file created and it is as if no parameter is
given for the search.

So, the question is how to pass correctly the parameter of the country
Afghanistan so that I will get as a reply the html file that shows
the time in Afghanistan.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: 1. Does worldtimeserver.com provide an API? I couldn't find any info about one on their site. 2. Did you check the `curl` man page for usage instructions? Type `man curl` in your terminal. 3. Consider using a time service with a [real API like Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start). 4. You don't need to get local time from a service necessarily, just use the UTC offset and do the math.

Comment: If there is a way to get the time zone of a location like Sydney automatically from google using a bash script I will be glad to know. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Google or any service to get the timezone of Sydney, Australia - it will always be `UTC+10:00`.

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear. Sydney is just an example, I am not interested in a specific location. I am interested in a script that given any location indicated by city will return the zone for that location.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, but if you don't use an official API it may break without notice

```
code=TR; curl -s https://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_$code.aspx
```

the file is very large, may not have much practical value.  I piped to `grep -A1 'id="theTime"'` to get the time only...

Comment: Thanks  a lot, it helps. The question now is how to get the code automatically with a bash script. For example the script will get  a parameter such as Sydney and use some web site to get the code for Sydney which is AU-NSW, if that were possible then I could use your suggestion to get the time on Sydney.

Comment: You don't need an external system for timezone conversion. Check TZ use with `date`

Comment: I looked at TZ and it is not general enough. If I give TZ a city like Sydney I don't see that it will give me the answer. I would like something more general like what the web site do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to get the UTC time (or other time zone) directly out of worldclock without using the API with just curl and egrep:

```
$ export UTC=$(curl -s https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc|\
egrep -o "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]")

$ echo $UTC
20:37:08
```

Just note that not using the API, front end changes could break the output.

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your answer, removing the un-needed comments and not signing your name.